# C#: Object to string array. [*] to [] error (Knowing both VB.NET as well as C# helps)

Tags: c#, vb.net, arrays, object, combobox

I have been assigned to Convert a VB.NET project to C# and I got stuck. I am using a class called RsiOPCAuto, but I don't think that I'll have to go into to much detail into explaining how it works. Let's just get on with my issue.

So basicly what i do is grabbing an object from my class using this code:

```
public partial class FrmPartialMain : Form
{
    RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer oOpcServer;
    public FrmPartialMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        object RsiOPCAuto;
        object oOPCList;

        oOpcServer = new RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer();
        oOPCList = oOpcServer.GetOPCServers();
```

So far, so good. By adding a watch I can see that oOPCList now have the value {string[1..4]}.

Now I want to put these four strings into a combo box. I do this with a simple for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= oOPCList.Length; i++)
{
    cboServer.Items.Add(oOPCList[i]);
}
```

***Edit: Scratch that, changed this to a much nicer foreach loop.***

Even though this object now functions as a string array both the oOPCList.Length and (oOPCList[i]) get errors:

**.Length:**
Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**oOPCList[i]:**
Error 2 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

I bet it's the simplest thing but I just can't see it, help is very much appreciated and if there's anything else you need to know be sure to ask :-)

PS. It might be worth mentioning that I have tried some different ways to convert the object to a string array but I continuously get an error telling me that I can not convert system.string[*] to system.string[].

This is the VB.NET code that I am converting:

```
Friend Class frmPartialMain
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
        Dim oOpcServer As RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer
        Private Sub frmPartialMain_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As  System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim RsiOPCAuto As Object
            Dim oOPCList() As Object
            Dim i As Integer

            oOpcServer = New RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer
            oOPCList = oOpcServer.GetOPCServers
            For i = LBound(oOPCList) To UBound(oOPCList)
                cboServer.Items.Add(oOPCList(i))
            Next i
```

Comment: Why convert? You should be able to use the types from the VB.NET assembly in any .NET language (assuming it is CLS compliant).

Comment: Is there the option to use ToArray(), e.g. oOpcServer = new RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer().ToArray();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the return value of `GetOPCServers` to an `object` first, then to an `Array`, because this method returns a `dynamic` type. You can't directly cast to a `string[]` because strong-typed arrays that are not 0-based are not supported by C#. After the cast, you need to call `Cast<string>` to get a strong typed enumerable, over which you can iterate:

```
IEnumerable<string> oOPCList;

oOpcServer = new RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer();
oOPCList = ((Array)(object)oOpcServer.GetOPCServers()).Cast<string>();
```

Furthermore, you would be better off using a `foreach` loop, because it is a lot more readable:

```
foreach(var item in oOPCList)
    cboServer.Items.Add(item);
```

---

The strange cast first to `object`, then to `Array`, and then to `IEnumerable<string>` via `Cast<string>` is needed because of the following:

`GetOPCServers` returns a `dynamic` type. Trying to access that dynamic instance in any way - even via a call to `GetType` triggers an `InvalidCastException`. Therefore, it first needs to be cast to `object` so it no longer is a dynamic type. After that, we can cast it to an `Array`, the only supported way in C# to work with non-zero-based arrays. But `Array` is not strong typed, so we append the call to `Cast<string>` to get a strong typed enumerable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like the foreach loop, looks very nice. Didn't even think of that one! I do still get the error; "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'." on "oOPCList = (string[])oOpcServer.GetOPCServers();".

Comment: @Charp: string[*] means the array is indexed starting at 1. See the link in my answer on how to work with such an array.

Comment: @Charp: Please see update. It is not necessary to use the complex way described in Paul's link.

Comment: Hmm seems like this was harder than i origianlly expected. Again, very much appreciate you helping me, both of you. I do not seem to be able to add .Cast<string> after OPCServer() for some reason, though.

Comment: @Charp: Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your C# file.

Comment: Yes it is there. I can't add anything after OPCServer() as it seems. I tried making a new variable that equals oOPCList.Cast<string>() but I'm not sure what type it should be, string[] did not work.

Comment: @Charp: What is the return type of `GetOPCServers()` according to the obejct browser?

Comment: ([object Node = System.Type.Missing])

Comment: @Charp: That doesn't look like a method signature. Maybe you can post a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry I just started this account to ask this question, I have never used this forum before. How do I post a screen shot here?

Comment: Just put it on imgur.com and post the link or edit your question and choose Image from the toolbar.

Comment: This is all the text i get from GetOPCServers() in the Objects Browser: public virtual dynamic GetOPCServers([object Node = System.Type.Missing])
    Member of RsiOPCAuto.OPCServerClass

Comment: Still getting that same error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'."

Comment: @Charp: Impossible, in my code there is no such cast... Please make sure you have it exactly like in my answer.

Comment: I commented out every other code and wrote your code again from scratch, here's what happens: http://imgur.com/CwZq0

Comment: @Charp: Ah, you forgot to mention that this is a runtime error. Sorry, please try the edited answer ;-)

Comment: If this doesn't work, try this: `foreach(string item in ((Array)oOpcServer.GetOPCServers()))` or `foreach(string item in ((IEnumerable)oOpcServer.GetOPCServers()))`

Comment: The updated code gives me two new errors but it fixed the runtime error, the first foreach loop in your comment gave me the same [] error again and the second gave me one error which i fixed buy adding <string> after IEnumerable. But I still get the runtime error.

Comment: @Charp: I assume that the returned array isn't one dimensional, is this possible?

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I have never worked with multidimensional arrays, is there any way for me to check this?

Comment: @Charp: Wow... OK, the problem is that a dynamic type is involved. Please see updated answer. This finally should work...

Comment: IT WORKED! You Sir are amazing. Can't believe you stuck by me for 5 hours. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can only access the members of an object available at the reference type. So if you put a string array into a field or variable of type `object` you'll only be able to access those members defined on object itself (such as `ToString`)<sup>†</sup>.

`string[*]` means the array is an array that is indexed at something other than zero, which usually means it's indexed starting at 1. (I can't remember off hand how to convert these but I will look it up.)

Edit: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733008/83264) on how to work with a non-zero based array in C#.

Whilst it's possible to create and work with such an array, its usage in C# is exceptional so you will have to refer to it via a variable of type `Array` as `string[*]` is not valid C#.

<sup>† It would still be possible to access them indirectly using Reflection.</sup>

Comment: Looks like this was alot harder then I thought, since I'm working with an object variable I can not use that code, unfortunately. Not as far as I know anyway. If you think there's a way to use my code that way then I'd love to see it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Charp: you should be able to cast the variable to type Array.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared oOPCList as an object which doesnt have a length property and hence cannot be iterated on. What does the oOpcServer.GetOPCServers() return? Is it an Array?

Declare oOPCList as the same type and you can iterate using for or foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(var opc in oOpcServer.GetOPCServers().ToList()) {
    cboServer.Items.Add(oOPCList[i]);
}
```

Comment: If GetOPCServers does indeed return an object, that will not help either.

Answer (score 0):

You get this errors because oOPCList is an object. It doesn't contains lenght nor [] indexers. Use type returned by  oOpcServer.GetOPCServers()