# Convert dynamic System.String[*] to System.String[] type in .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

[image]I have c# project, in which a data type is unknown to me.

As shown in the picture, the data type is from a class which has no method or property, but when I hover over it, it shows the items.

Also, I get an error when I try the foreach command.

Also, it is not convertible to List or Dictionary or Stringp[].
Please guide me to work on it. Thanks

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a1 = new OPCServer();

        var anOPCDAServers=new OPCServer();
        var serverName="FARATARH-PC";
        var AllOPCDAServers = new List<string>();
        var asw = anOPCDAServers.GetOPCServers("FARATARH-PC");
        //Console.WriteLine(typeof(asw).ToString);

        foreach (var item in asw)
        {
            //AllOPCDAServers.Add(item);
        }


        //var nod = AllOPCDAServers[4];


        //a1.Connect(serverName, );




    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNlBf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put code *as text* in your question, along with the error message *as text*. A screenshot can be useful for additional information, but the code should always be present as text, along with contextual descriptions (in this case, that you're talking to a COM object...)

Comment: Put `if (asw is System.Collections.IEnumerable)` before your `foreach` and check if you can enumerate

Comment: Yes it is, Surprisingly!

Comment: This is not a repeated question. If so, the proposed answer would work for me. That person has been using a differenet dll.

Answer (score 1):

asw is an array of dynamic object. Dont use var type to loop instead use `dynamic` as the type.

```
foreach (dynamic item in aswItems)
{
   // code here
}
```

Comment: Again Unhandled error, Unable to convert System.String[*] to System.String[]

Comment: can you post the full error. Also post your code not the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In theorie, you could just do

```
string[] foo = asw;
```

and work with this.

Comment: It does not work. It gives and unhanded error. It is : Unable to convert System.String[*] to System.String[]

Answer (score 0):

Try casting AsEnumerable() which would allow you to enumerate the array.

```
foreach(var item in asw.AsEnumerable())
{
}
```

Comment: AsEnumerable() is not defined for system.array. It has type:System.string[*}

Answer (score 0):

> String[*] indicates an array that can have a lower bound other than zero. They are incompatible with a regular string[], but you can still cast it to a System.Array and work with it that way. So try

```
IEnumerable<string> oOPCList;

oOpcServer = new RsiOPCAuto.OPCServer();
oOPCList = ((Array)(object)oOpcServer.GetOPCServers()).Cast<string>();
foreach(var item in oOPCList)
    ...
```

---

The strange cast first to `object`, then to `Array`, and then to `IEnumerable<string>` via `Cast<string>` is needed because of the following:

`GetOPCServers` returns a `dynamic` type. Trying to access that dynamic instance in any way - even via a call to `GetType` triggers an `InvalidCastException`. Therefore, it first needs to be cast to `object` so it no longer is a dynamic type. After that, we can cast it to an `Array`, the only supported way in C# to work with non-zero-based arrays. But `Array` is not strong typed, so we append the call to `Cast<string>` to get a strong typed enumerable.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940013/c-object-to-string-array-to-error-knowing-both-vb-net-as-well-as-c-sh)

Comment: Nice Idea, but not still working. Again the same Unhandled error.

Comment: @Amir_Controller what error says? Could you update your question with code and full error message?

Comment: ok, as long as you have it in as `dynamic` I updated the answer.

Comment: A Good step forward. Converting to Object it keeps the items, but converting to array it gives a null array. Marvelous!