# What is the difference between T[,] and T[*,*]?

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

My Google-Jitsu is failing me.  Question is in the title... What is the difference between `T[,]` and `T[*,*]`?
I am looking for a 2, 2-1/2 part answer:

1. Layman's (or super architect's) plain english explaination with example code.
2. Link to the formal documentation of this distinction.

   Bonus: Point to subsection and page number in the C# 4 spec that defines this.  (It is not in sect 12 "Arrays")

I got this notion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/e6f84f77-1a09-4dd9-a2af-eb3a54e9c7bc).

Comment: You typically get these kind of objects from COM interop.  A SAFEARRAY with a non-zero lower bound, usually it is 1.  Use Array.GetValue() and GetLower/UpperBound() to convert it.

Comment: @Hans, Yep got them from the Excel PIA and hit that out of bounds issue.   See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357092/fastest-way-to-convert-t-to-t

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`T[]`  means a zero-based array of T  *(array[0] is its first element)*

`T[*]` means a non-zero-based array of T *(array[0] is not its first element and can even be out of bounds)*

The [link from your question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/e6f84f77-1a09-4dd9-a2af-eb3a54e9c7bc) explains that there is no array of type `T[*,*]`, because all multi-dimensional arrays of `T[,]` are treated as arrays with unknown lower-bound.

Code snippet below shows how you can create an instance of `T[*]`. Note that you can not cast it to `T[]`, because they are different types. `a[0]` here will throw an OutOfRangeException, the index of the first element in this array is 1 *(ah, good old Pascal days...)*.

```
Array a = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(String), new Int32[] { 1 }, new Int32[] { 1 });
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());    // System.String[*]
```

[More example code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34195/Non-Zero-Based-Arrays-and-Interface)

**Bonus.** The C# language spec says, *"The indices of the elements of an array range from 0 to Length - 1"*. Obviously, the language does not provide built-in support for non-zero-based arrays, it's just a custom data structure that you can create; although specific in a sense that the compiler happens to have a special symbol for its type and VS uses standard array visualizer for them when you're debugging.

See also:

[How to create a 1-Dimensional Array in C# with index starting at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728409/how-to-create-a-1-dimensional-array-in-c-sharp-with-index-starting-at-1)

[C#: Nonzero-based arrays are not CLS-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955732/c-nonzero-based-arrays-are-not-cls-compliant)

Comment: Does "zero-based array" mean lower bounds = 0? And "non-zero-based array" mean lower bounds !=0?

Comment: @dFlat: yep, that's exactly what it means

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answers

Answer (score 3):

## *Actually*...

#### C# *does* support 1-dimensional arrays... sort of.

Well, it does... if you use `var`.

First, you would need to compile this into an assembly using `ILAsm.exe` (I know, this isn't C#... yet):

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )
    .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly ArrayHelper { }
.module ArrayHelper.dll
.subsystem 0x0003
.class public ArrayHelper   
{
    .method public hidebysig static !!T[...]
        CastTo1D<T>(class [mscorlib]System.Array 'array') cil managed
    {
        ldarg.0
        castclass  !!T[...]
        ret
    }
    .method public hidebysig static !!T[...] Create1D<T>(int32 len) cil managed
    {
        ldarg.0
        newobj     instance void !!T[...]::.ctor(int32)
        ret
    }
    .method public hidebysig static !!T[...]
        Create1D<T>(int32 lowerBound, int32 length) cil managed
    {
        ldarg.0
        ldarg.1
        newobj     instance void !!T[...]::.ctor(int32, int32)
        ret
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var my1DArray = ArrayHelper.Create<int>(1, 5);
```

to create a 1-D array of length 5 with lower bound 1.

Heck, even Visual Studio supports this!

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

Hope you have fun with it.

Comment: Interesting. The picture is not loading for me... Can you fix it?

Comment: @Yacoder: That's weird... it's fine for me. Try clicking [the link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0rKOO.png) instead?

Comment: I see, it works now. Yeah, IDE and compiler seems to be aware of that case, though the C# spec only considers array types that are zero-based. There's no syntax to write smth like string[*] in C#.